# I do not show any folder in VS while pul the code, but it shows in the file explorer

Tags: git, file, visual-studio-2019, git-pull

I am facing a problem that files and folders are not showing in Visual Studio while taking pull or add from file Explorer
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkS7g.jpg)

I cleaned the solution multiple times and reopened vs multiple times.
[I click on the show all files button it shows files but it is not working]

[image]

Comment: Try right clicking the project in solution explorer and unloading it, then reload it.  If that doesn't work, try selecting all the controller files and right click and select include in project